# Pivot with limited number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem with query in Microsoft SQL environment. I'm getting serial numbers which I want to transform from rows to columns due to customer's template. Limitation for me is customer's template - max number of columns could be 10. I don't know how to reach my vision where each 11-20, 21-30, etc. columns will be in new row. See example with 13 rows from database:

What I'm able to do:

| Product01 | Product02 | Product03 | Product04 | Product05 | Product06 | Product07 | Product08 | Product09 | Product10 | Product11 | Product12 | Product13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BK018001B6 | BK018001B7 | BK018001B8 | BK018001B9 | BK018001BB | BK018001BC | BK018001BD | BK018001BF | BK018001BG | BK018001BH | BK018001BJ | BK018001BK | BK018001BL |

What I want to do:

| Product01 | Product02 | Product03 | Product04 | Product05 | Product06 | Product07 | Product08 | Product09 | Product10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BK018001B6 | BK018001B7 | BK018001B8 | BK018001B9 | BK018001BB | BK018001BC | BK018001BD | BK018001BF | BK018001BG | BK018001BH |
| BK018001BJ | BK018001BK | BK018001BL |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I have found following working playground for Microsoft SQL: https://sqlzoo.net/. Unfortunately there is no way to provide you working playground as a link. You need to copy my SQL code to reproduce that:

```
CREATE TABLE #sourceTable(SerialNo VARCHAR(20), ProductRowNumber VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #sourceTable
(
    SerialNo,
    ProductRowNumber
)
VALUES
    ('BK018001B6', 'Product01'),
    ('BK018001B7', 'Product02'),
    ('BK018001B8', 'Product03'),
    ('BK018001B9', 'Product04'),
    ('BK018001BB', 'Product05'),
    ('BK018001BC', 'Product06'),
    ('BK018001BD', 'Product07'),
    ('BK018001BF', 'Product08'),
    ('BK018001BG', 'Product09'),
    ('BK018001BH', 'Product10'),
    ('BK018001BJ', 'Product11'),
    ('BK018001BK', 'Product12'),
    ('BK018001BL', 'Product13')

CREATE TABLE #productsTempTable (ProductSerialNo VARCHAR(20), ProductRowNumber VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #productsTempTable
SELECT SerialNo, ProductRowNumber FROM #sourceTable

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
                    (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ProductRowNumber)
                    FROM #productsTempTable
                    GROUP BY ProductRowNumber
                    ORDER BY ProductRowNumber
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                , 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' FROM 
             (
                SELECT ProductSerialNo, ProductRowNumber
                FROM #productsTempTable
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
                MAX(ProductSerialNo)
                FOR ProductRowNumber IN (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;

DROP table #productsTempTable, #sourceTable
```

In real the column "ProductRowNumber" I'm composing this way for completeness:

```
'Product' + RIGHT(100 + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p.id)), 2) AS 'ProductRowNumber'
```

Could you help me with this issue please?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your `@@Version`?

Comment: Are the `ProductRowNumber` column values actually "Product01", "Product02" so always "Product" and a number?

Comment: The version is: "Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU24) (KB5001228) - 14.0.3391.2 (X64)   Apr 28 2021 10:32:18   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)".

Comment: You can create a working demo to share at [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)

Comment: Is your `Productrownumber` column manufactured or is it actually part of your source data? And is the numerical ordering related to the serial numbers or arbitrary?

Comment: OK, working demo is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d7197df160b35155ae1965b698bc772)

Comment: ```ProductRowNumber``` I'm describing at the bottom of the question. It's a ```Product``` as a constant and after that it's a value from 01 to 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pivot does not need to be dynamic. We just need to do a bit of arithmetic with row number:

```sql
SELECT
  Product01, Product02, Product03, Product04, Product05, Product06, Product07, Product08, Product09, Product10
FROM (
    SELECT
      SerialNo,
      rn10 = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductRowNumber) - 1) / 10,
      ProductRN = CONCAT(
        'Product',
         FORMAT((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductRowNumber) - 1) % 10 + 1, '00'))
    FROM #sourceTable st
) st
PIVOT (
    MAX(SerialNo) FOR ProductRN IN
      (Product01, Product02, Product03, Product04, Product05, Product06, Product07, Product08, Product09, Product10)
) pvt;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa8406df4ec5d35b1919c688f5ab2037)

In your real query, you can replace the `ROW_NUMBER` with your existing row-numbering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used your solution for my case and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the conditional aggregate approach is pretty simple:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 10 = 1 then serialno end) as prod_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 2 then serialno end) as prod_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 3 then serialno end) as prod_3,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 4 then serialno end) as prod_4,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 5 then serialno end) as prod_5,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 6 then serialno end) as prod_6,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 7 then serialno end) as prod_7,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 8 then serialno end) as prod_8,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 9 then serialno end) as prod_9,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 10 then serialno end) as prod_10
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by ProductRowNumber) as seqnum
      from sourceTable t
     ) t
group by ceiling(seqnum / 10.0)
order by min(seqnum);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b10e42baa74585a0a233a962166e5a6e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yes, this works fine for my case. Thank you very much for sharing it.